# UPS API .net not resolve namespace TrackWSSample.TrackWebReference

Tags: c#, .net, api, ups

I am trying to write a simple web form in .net that checks UPS tracking status.

I downloaded the API and example from UPS< i was able to run the example and get response.

The issue is that the example is written as a console C# program and not as a web page, so I created a new web site, and copied the code.
I added the WSDL, but i am still receiving: "The type or namespace name 'TrackWebReference' does not exist in the namespace 'TrackWSSample' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I cant find any info about how to import this namespace, and I cant find anything in the example that give me a clue.

[image: code]

Thank you,
Idan

Comment: What is the name you used for the service reference?

Comment: TrackWSSample.TrackWebReference

Answer (score 8):

The error was caused by wrong Web Reference Url that points to the ***Track.wsdl*** file. You need to update the path to the right file and update the Web Reference in Visual Studio.

To update the path for the web reference URL, do these steps:

- From Solution Explorer, select ***Web References --> TrackWebReference***
- Look at Properties tables, ***Web Reference URL***, it should be "**C:\arun_UPS\UPS\codeworkspace\DodgeTrackSchema\Track.wsdl**". Change this path to your local Track.wsdl file. You can find this file in the **CodeSamples\Track\Dotnet\TrackWSSample\TrackWSSample\Web Reference** folder.
- Finally, regenerate the Reference.cs file by right click on the **TrackWebReference** again on Solutions Explorer, and select ***Update Web Reference***.

Now you should have your problem resolved.